# Why can't I use role authorization in my API controller

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I created a react project with the react template in asp.net core with individual user accounts. I have looked around and found out I needed to add roles in the startup file and add a profile service, which seems to have half worked.

I can see the roles in my authorization token like this:

```js
"role": [
    "admin",
    "bookkeeping" ],
```

But when I add the `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` tag to my controller the requests are now forbidden, even when i can see my token includes the role "admin".

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

This is the Profile service:

```cs
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> mUserManager;

    public ProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        mUserManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await mUserManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

        IList<string> roles = await mUserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        IList<Claim> roleClaims = new List<Claim>();
        foreach (string role in roles)
        {
            roleClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
        context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(roleClaims);
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and this is my startup file:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole",
                 policy => policy.RequireRole("admin"));
        });

        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );
        services.AddRazorPages();

        // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

A small version of my API controller:

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleDataController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public SampleDataController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }   
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrderList()
    {

        return _db.Order.ToList();
    }

}
```

And my fetch method

```js
async populateOrderList() {
    const token = await authService.getAccessToken();
    const response = await fetch('api/SampleData/GetOrderList', {
        headers: !token ? {} : { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` }
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ orderList: data });
}
```

As you can see in my startup file I have also tried using a policy, with the tag `[Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdministratorRole")]` instead. Also it works fine when i just use `[Authorize]`

Edit: My api controllers are in the same projekt as my identity server.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What happens when you remove the Authorize attribute? If it still shows as unauthorized then there is another cause, e.g. something with cors.

Comment: Hi @RuardvanElburg, Yes it works just fine without Authorize.

Comment: I wonder, do you have the working result of this somewhere we could see? I am running into similiar issues. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your default claimtype for role in startup like this:

```
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role;
        });
```

Comment: Hi @Mehrdad, Thanks for the help. It is sadly still forbidden.

Comment: please try [Authorize(LocalApi.PolicyName)] and [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] together on your controller

Comment: Hi @Mehrdad, Thanks again. I'm now getting an internal server error. Response :  System.InvalidOperationException: The AuthorizationPolicy named: 'IdentityServerAccessToken' was not found.

Comment: i'm working with identityserver4 for 2 years, and right now test Authorize with roles on my controller, there is no any problem, i think something is missed. whould you share your project on some where with me?

Comment: i think your controllers and identityserver endpoints are in the same project, am i right? if so, add services.AddLocalApiAuthentication(); in start will fix this error

Comment: Hi @Mehrdad. Yes they are in the same project. But I don't entirely understand what this does. Would it be possible for you to explain it in a little more detail?

Comment: when you have identityserver and your apis in the same project, you should add some extra configs, for more information and figure out what are this config read [this](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html#adding-more-api-endpoints) document please

Comment: after this all configs, does your problem exist?

Comment: It no longer shows it as forbidden, but its still unauthorized somehow. I think i might be missing something with the registering of the API  as a api resource, but i might be wrong.

Comment: share your logs befor and after sending your request, identityserver logs are great

Comment: I changed the order in the Startup file and now it worked.